# Package com.google.maps.android.geojson does not exist in com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, geojson, android-maps-utils

When I upgraded my *android project* to ***android-maps-utils to 0.5+***, 
the entire ***geojson*** package was missing.

[image: Related Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geojson Class moved in to package *com.google.maps.android.***data***.geojson*.

Changing the *import* to:

```
import com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.*
```